# Is there a way to change the default EXE icon in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, icons, delphi-7, exe

Embarcadero just [released](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40476) a whole bunch of neat looking icons that I'd like to use to make my Delphi 7 and 2009 apps look fancier. Is there a setting (or hack) in those IDEs that lets me change the default exe icon?

Comment: I'm not talking about the icon in project options per project, I'm talking about changing the torch or the 7 with the lightning bolt to permanently be something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a resource editor to find the icon in the Delphi ide or bpl and change it to something else. That would be permanent for all new projects.

Comment: Yeah, do you know what that is?  I searched for all the .res files and couldn't find anything. (using Delphi 7)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that Andrey answered exactly what you asked I assume you want to add more icons to your executable than just the one you can set in the project option? This can be done by adding a *.rc file to the project. The following line should go into your project:

```
{$R 'Icons.res' 'Icons.rc'}
```

The rc file is a plain text file that Delphi compiles into a res. To the rc file add 1 icon per line like this:

```
XIcon01 ICON ".\Images\ico\ADDRESS2.ico"
XIcon02 ICON ".\Images\ico\ADDRESS3.ico"
XIcon03 ICON ".\Images\ico\ADDRESS4.ico"
```

The first part is the name of the icon. I chose names that come after Mainicon alphabetically with Mainicon being the icon that you define in the project options. I'm not sure (maybe somebody can confirm?) but I think that Delphi compiles the first icon as the application icon so I made sure my additional icons sort later.
In case you want to change the application's icon at runtime you can use the 2 Application.Icon.LoadFromResource routines.
Hope that helps